# 'Invalid operator' error when running MATLAB script without changing working directory

Tags: matlab, cmd

I am trying to run a MATLAB script called `simulation.m` from the command line.

Matlab is located in `"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2022b\bin"`. The script is located in `"C:\path2"`.

If I do:

```
cd C:\path2
"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2022b\bin\matlab.exe" -batch simulation
```

This works flawlessly.

Now I want to run this in a single command without having to `cd` to a folder first.

I tried:

```
C:\Users\nd140\Desktop>"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2022b\bin\matlab.exe" -batch "C:\path2\simulation"
 C:\path2\simulation
   |
Invalid use of operator.
```

But as you can see I get an error.

Does anyone know how to run a MATLAB script without having to change the current directory first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What comes after `-batch` on the command line is a MATLAB command, not the name of a file. You could do two things:

1. Use the [`run`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/run.html) function in MATLAB

   ```
   "C:\path1\matlab.exe" -batch "run('C:\path2\simulation.m')"
   ```
2. Add the M-file path to the MATLAB search path before running the script.

   ```
   "C:\path1\matlab.exe" -batch "addpath('C:\path2'); simulation"
   ```

Comment: 3. Use the `-sd` option to set MATLAB's startup directory https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html#buklxlz-3 .